# sh how to Append variable's value to file into sh double quoted multiline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, sh, groovyshell

I need to append a string into a file. The string is made up of some prefix + variable.
This is in Jenkins pipeline using Groovy Syntax, so the only way to read variable's value is with multiline double quoted sh.

```
sh """
  ...some lines of code affecting the same scope...

  echo "sdk.dir=${ANDROID_HOME}" > local.properties

  ...some lines of code affecting the same scope...
  """
```

Actual:

```
WorkflowScript: 101: illegal string body character after dollar sign;

   solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 101, column 49.

     echo "sdk.dir=${ANDROID_HOME}" > local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to escape the $ sign with a slash as the error mentioned?

Also you’re using the same double quote, try to replace the “sh” command to a triple  single quote and use the double quote for the shell redirect as you did now.

Or last option you can escape the whole expression:

\\” express \\”

Comment: Thanks. Replacing external """ to ''' did the trick. ```'''```